# How to Use a Fine-Tuned CRAFT Model in EasyOCR

Tags: python, ocr, easyocr

I have successfully fine-tuned a CRAFT model using the training script provided in the [EasyOCR's CRAFT training documentation](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR/blob/master/trainer/craft/README.md), and obtained a file named CRAFT_clr_amp_48.pth. However, I am unsure how to integrate this fine-tuned model into EasyOCR for text detection purposes.

Could you please provide guidance or examples on how to use a fine-tuned .pth model with EasyOCR for text detection?

#### What I Tried

Following the model [API documentation](https://www.jaided.ai/easyocr/documentation/),
I set the model_storage_directory="./saved_models/test" in the Reader class and placed the .pth file in the test folder (this worked fine for recognition fine-tuning).

#### Result

It displayed the following message and seemed to download a new CRAFT .pth file, which was then used:

> Downloading detection model, please wait. This may take several minutes depending upon your network connection.

Since craft_mlt_25k.pth was downloaded, I renamed my fine-tuned model to craft_mlt_25k.pth and executed it. However, I received the following message and craft_mlt_25k.pth was re-downloaded:

> MD5 hash mismatch, possible file corruption. Re-downloading the detection model, please wait. This may take several minutes depending upon your network connection.

I then specified my fine-tuned model's .pth file in the detector parameter.

#### Result

No error was produced, but there was no change in detection accuracy. It seemed unlikely to make a difference since it's a boolean value.